# oAuth2 Android approach

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a token provider on my Spring Boot server and i want to know, what is the best approach to use it in my Android application? Currently, i can get accessToken and refreshToken from Android, but how should i use it?

Should i save both tokens using SharedPrefs and when the accessToken is not valid anymore use the refresh token to obtain another? What expiration time to set for the both tokens?

Should i check in every request from the Android to the external server if the response is Unauthorized and then make this procedure in order to get the new accessToken?

Comment: Libraries like okhttp allows to use feature called interceptors. This allow to do some generic checks in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you request from the Android device to the your server in Server code first check if the token is present in the cache(if you have cached it after the token was generated,also have expiration time in your cache for the token) if the token is not present in cache token is expired generate Unauthorized response, you will have to make a new request to generate the token if its expired or invalid and then again cache it.

Comment: how to store the expire? from the server i get expires_in: 3277 seconds for example, when i get the new token should i save it using timestamp now + expires_in in order to check the expiration for the refresh token and access token before making a new request to the server?

Comment: regarding expire time It depends on the caching solution you are using to store the token ,each caching library provides a way to configure the expiry time for an entry.you don't need to save timestamp now + expires_in,as say you configure the expire time as 5 mins the token will be valid for 5 mins and then will expire ,any further request will cause unauthorized response and then you should ask for new/refresh token,...so as to use the services